# How to find part of string?

Tags: python, text-search

I am working with a string. I could find the part of string I need but not all of it. Which part of my code needs to change?

```
s = "3D(filters:!!(),refreshInterval:(pause:!!t,value:0),time:(from:!%272019-10-01T20:28:50.088Z!%27,to:now))%26_a%3D(description:!%27!%27,filters:!!(),fullScreenMode:!!"

report_time = s[s.find("time:(") + 1:s.find("))")]
```

Output I need:

```
>>> report_time
'time:(from:!%272019-10-01T20:28:50.088Z!%27,to:now))'
```

Output I have:

```
>>> report_time
'ime:(from:!%272019-10-01T20:28:50.088Z!%27,to:now)'
```

Comment: The output you should be getting is `ime:(from:!%272019-10-01T20:28:50.088Z!%27,to:now`

Answer (score 1):

You put the "+1" on the wrong index.  You need to pick up from the first `find` location and go one character *past* the second to pick up the extra right parenthesis.  This last needs even one *more* character (thanks to `smac89 for catching that).

```
report_time = s[s.find("time:("):s.find("))") + 2]
```

Output:

```
'time:(from:!%272019-10-01T20:28:50.088Z!%27,to:now))'
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively use a regular expression, e.g:

```
import re
re.search(r'(time:\(.*\)\))', s).group(1)
```

Explanation: group(1) returns the matching content of the 1st set of parentheses.  .* matches any characters in between. The parentheses in your search therm need to be escaped.

Output:

```
'time:(from:!%272019-10-01T20:28:50.088Z!%27,to:now))'
```